# what is alt mempool in EIP-4337 (Account Abstraction)

Tags: blockchain

In https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4337, the authors say "Users send UserOperation objects into a separate mempool". i was wondering what it means.. and now, i think that they refer to off-chain memory pool for storing Pending UserOperation(High-level Transaction). so, i think that 'alt mempool' is probably 'alternative memory pool' that is implemented based distributed in-memory key-value store (e.g. Redis) that stores pending UserOperations.

Did I understand correctly? how do you think about it?

what i did : read and read and think.. about eip-4337.
what i expect : check whether i understand it correctly or not

Comment: Is this alt mempool live? Was it already implemented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you pretty much understand it!

EIP-4337 creates a decentralized network of bundlers that accepts UserOperations, the pseudo-transaction object for EIP-4337. Bundlers can accept transactions from private mempools and a shared canonical mempool. This mempool is not very different from the transaction pool used in Ethereum. In fact, the [EIP-4337 mempool will very likely be modeled after the Ethereum mempool](https://www.stackup.sh/blog/meeting-recap-public-mempool-kickoff).